# Python for loop: index a one-item list in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing, split

I have a list containing lists of strings that I am trying to split. Some of the lists only have one string, but others have more.

ex: qnum = [[(' 1 2 3')], [(' 1 1 1'),(' 3 4 5')],[(' 5 6 7')]]

```
print 'qnum', qnum[0][0].split()
print 'qnum', qnum[1][1].split()
```

Gives: qnum ['1', '2', '3'] and qnum ['3', '4', '5']  which is perfect. But

```
qnum2 = []
for i in qnum:  #which list in qnum
    for n in qnum[i]:   #which string in the list
        qnum2.append( qnum_low[i][n].split() )
```

Breaks on the first iteration at "for n in qnum_low[i]:" resulting in an error "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list"

I should be able to index to a list with one item in it, right? Seeing how I just did it above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `TypeError` originates from your assumption that `for i in qnum` iterates over *indices into* `qnum`. It doesn't—it iterates over  *the items themselves*.  That usually yields shorter, cleaner code:

```
qnum2 = []
for sublist in qnum:
    for item in sublist:
         qnum2.append(item.split())
```

So much so, in fact, that these four lines can be condensed into a one-line assignment using list comprehension syntax:

```
qnum2 = [item.split() for sublist in qnum for item in sublist]
```

If you ever do actually need the indices `i` and `n` for some other purpose in the loop, that's where `enumerate` can help you:

```
for i, sublist in enumerate(qnum):
     for n, item in enumerate(sublist):
         ...
```

If for some reason you insist on iterating over just the indices, then you're usually stuck with this rather clunky, unPythonic syntax:

```
for i in range(len(qnum)):
    for n in range(len(qnum[i])):
        ....
```